# Closing and Disposing a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, web-services

The `Close` method on an `ICommunicationObject` can throw two types of exceptions as MSDN outlines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520.aspx). I understand why the `Close` method can throw those exceptions, but what I don't understand is why the `Dispose` method on a service proxy calls the `Close` method without a `try` around it. Isn't your `Dispose` method the one place where you want make sure you don't throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to be a common design pattern in .NET code. Here is a citation from [Framework design guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)

> Consider providing method Close(), in addition to the Dispose(), if close is standard terminology in the area. When doing so, it is important that you make the Close implementation identical to Dispose ...

Here is a [blog post](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx) in which you can find workaround for this System.ServiceModel.ClientBase design problem

Comment: the code using WCF Proxy Generator in VS 2008 when I add Service Reference is bad code because not good practices for disposing (close) ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, typically Dispose is one of the places you want to ensure exceptions aren't thrown. However, based on this MSDN [forum thread](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=855018&SiteID=1) there were some historical reasons for this behavior. As such, the recommended pattern is the try{Close}/catch{Abort} paradigm.