# Entity Framework "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" with 'large' data on Azure

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am using Entity Framework (v4.0) to connect to SQL Azure (I have the March SDK installed) and getting a `InvalidOperationException` when trying to query a table. The message of the exception is `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.` and the stack trace clearly shows that this is failing internally in EF when it attempts to get the column header:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadColumnHeader(Int32 i) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i) 
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) 
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) 
at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() 
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
at Service.LoadSettings() in C:\Service.svc.cs 
at SyncInvokeLoadSettings(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

This is specifically related to the data in a column in the second table (Settings in the example below). This works perfectly fine if I query another table (like the Users in the example below) or exclude quering the that column.
Example of the code:

```
using (var db = new DBEntities()) 
{ 
    var users = (from u in db.Users 
                 where u.PK == userid 
                 select u).ToList();

    if (users.Any()) 
    { 
        var selectedUser = users.Single(); 
        if (selectedUser.Password.Equals(passwordHash)) 
        { 
            // ****************************** 
            // * error is on the next line! * 
            // ****************************** 
            var settings = (from s in db.Settings 
                            where s.User == selectedUser.PK 
                            select s).ToList(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I've tried re-creating the tables, changing tables names, column names and data types and none of it helps. If the table is empty or the column contains a 'small' set of data then it works but the moment I have a single row in it with a 'large' data it fails!

What do I mean by small & large, well they not really smal & large for SQL:

- 'small' < ~8k
- 'large' > ~8k

I can confirm the issue is not related to me [disposing the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959592/disposing-datacontext-causes-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed) early.

---

**Updates**

1. This is only on read, inserts work fine.
2. This does not occur when I use LINQ to SQL, just with EF.
3. [Bug logged with Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651552/entity-framework-invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present-with-large-data-on-azure) as I suspect this is not normal behaviour.

Comment: i'm getting a similar error. any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the CommandTimeout on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I increased the command timeout, and it worked.

```
using (var db = new DBEntities()) 
{ 
//setting the CommandTimeout before the .ToList()
db.CommandTimeout = 120;

var users = (from u in db.Users 
             where u.PK == userid 
             select u).ToList();

if (users.Any()) 
{ 
    var selectedUser = users.Single(); 
    if (selectedUser.Password.Equals(passwordHash)) 
    { 
        // ****************************** 
        // * error is on the next line! * 
        // ****************************** 
        var settings = (from s in db.Settings 
                        where s.User == selectedUser.PK 
                        select s).ToList(); 
    } 
} 
}
```