# Entity Framework 6 materialization error on Azure SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

My web site is on MVC5 + EntityFramework 6 code first. When running localy it works fine. But after deployment (as Azure website and Azure SQL DB) it has materialization errors like [this](http://joxi.ru/vAWDqq8skjO8Vr). On different pages there are different errors, but all of them is about materialization.

What we tried to solve this problem:

1. Increased database timeout from 30 to 120 like suggested here [Entity Framework “Invalid attempt to read when no data is present” with 'large' data on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310764/entity-framework-invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present-with-large) . This did not help.
2. Connected to Azure DB from local web site instance in debug mode, but did not catch any errors.
3. Then we created one Azure resource group and placed both web site and DB in that group (At first time web site was in other group). And it looks like error is not apear any more.

So we found some workaround but did not fix error. And there is no garanties that this exceptions will never apear again. Did somebody faced such errors?

Comment: Looks like an application issue, when converting Guid to Int32 or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it is not a cause of error. Db was created via code first migrations and there are no custom mappings from sql responce to entities. And this error is not reachable even when debugging in VS it appears only when running on Azure.