# close connection database

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

private string GetPropertyCompany()
{
  var res=from b in dc.Tbl1 select b;
  string a;
  foreach(var item in res)
      a+=item.name;
  //    dc.Connection.Close();

  return a;
}
```

This code requires a close connection;

me should always close the connection;

without `dc.Connection.Close();` work fine!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Do I have to close the SQL Connection manually if I use Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400866/do-i-have-to-close-the-sql-connection-manually-if-i-use-linq) in particular

> LINQ to SQL will open and close connections when it needs to

Although if that code is in its own class you may wish to add a destructor that disposes of the data context, though that is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is the actual code, but nevertheless here's why you're having a problem.

```
var res = from b in dc.Tbl1 select b;
```

is not actually executed (that is, database isn't hit) until after you "access" `res` variable (i.e., 'foreach' over it), which apparently happens elsewhere. When you *do* access `res` the actual `DataContext` is already closed, hence the error.