# how to close connection after stored proc call in linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, connection

I'm facing a strange problem with my website that it doesn't seem to be using the connection pooling. I am using linq to sql to call stored procs and return the list of items but not sure if its closing the connections/disposing the data context class or not.

my code looks like this

```
public list<data.dto.category> getall()
{
var db = new mydatacontext();

return db.getCategories().ToList();
}
```

how do I make sure that I am closing the connections??

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389822/when-should-i-dispose-of-a-data-context or this related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/400866/284240 In short: they are closed automatically after the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your context with "using" statement.

```
    using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
    {
         // do stuff
    }
```