# How does .Net handle the connection in LINQ-To-Entity inside using context?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Linq-To-Entity in my project. But, I am hesitating to use `Stored Procedure` or `LINQ to Table or View` in some situations. But, I generally prefer to use LINQ, because of the *pleasent* syntax. I have searched google, but not found detailed asnwer to my question.

Let's consider this code:

```
using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
{
    var custs = from c in db.Customers where c.City == "London" select c;
    var edus = from c in db.Educations where c.Education != "2" select c;
    // ... and so on
}
```

*Questions*: 
1. Does it open a new connection for each query?  If it does, then it is not adviced to use above queries seperately? 
2. Also, could you advice me is there any situations that  I must use Stored Procedure instead of LINQ?

Comment: I have used sproc instead of linq when the query gets too complicated(unreadable) for linq or when there is no support for some things like spatial types in EF. also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures

Comment: The only time you MUST use a stored procedure in EF is when you want to use something that is not supported by EF. One example would be using the Full Text Search commands such as CONTAINS or if you need to write an XPath query on an xml column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it open a new connection for each query?

Sort of.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896325%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When a query method is called, the connection is opened, and it remains open until the ObjectResult has been completely consumed or disposed.

However, connections are *pooled* by .NET, so the same connection *object* will be reused (and I assume re-opened if necessary).

Note that a query is not *executed* until you enumerate over it (using `foreach`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, `Single`, `First`, etc.).  Until then *it's just a query*.  What that means is you must *do something* with the query *before* the context is disposed, or you'll get an exception.

> Are there any situations where I must use Stored Procedure instead of LINQ?

If your queries are too complex to be constructed using Linq, then a stored procedure is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Small nitpick but `AsEnumerable` does not execute the query.

Comment: @Dismissile True - I have removed it.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks, for the asnwer. Then does it mean that other two answers to my question are wrong? Also, from the docmentation it seems that I can explicitly open and close connection. Do you have information about that? `context.Connection.Open();` and `context.Connection.Close();`

Comment: Yes you can, but why would you?  EF is designed to manage connections effectively - unless you _know_ there's a problem, don't try to fix it yourself.

Comment: @DStanley Okay. I got you. Then, lets say I will use the sample code from my question to execute 10  query. From what you have said, it means that using SP will be faster than LINQ. Because, LINQ will re-open the connection. And the difference will be much, if I will execute 100 query. Am I true?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Possibly, but you'd have to measure it to be certain.  Even if it is, is the speed increase worth the overhead of maintaining sprocs outside of your main code?

Answer (score 2):

It does that in the constructor, when initializing the new context.

```
NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities();
```

Answer (score 2):

`LINQ` opens a connection when you initialize your context.

```
NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities()
```

And it will be closed when your `context` is disposed.

Comment: Are you certain about when they're opened?  The documentation I found states that there opened when a query is executed.

Comment: @DStanley After reading your answer, I do have my doubts. I guess what I thought about this is wrong.