# How to check if a StreamReader is still open?

Tags: c#

I try to "wrap" a `StreamReader` in a class `Fichier`, with some extra methods and attributes.

I want two things :

- The `StreamReader` opens automatically in the `Fichier` class;
- The `StreamReader` opens when we use the overrided method `ReadLine`, and not before (we need to modify the file before reading it with a `StreamReader`).

A piece of my code looks like this :

```
public string ReadLine()
{
    if (Reader == null || ???)
    {
        Reader = new StreamReader(Path);
    }
    return Reader.ReadLine();
}
```

At `???`, I want to check if the StreamReader has been closed. Indeed, if we do :

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
sr.Close();
```

`sr` is not null, but how to check that it is closed, and how to re-open it ?

If you wonder why I need to open and close `StreamReader`, it is because the `Fichier` object needs to exist anytime, but the file that it represents needs to be modified several times in an external program.

Comment: The `System.IO` namespace has a class named `File` so be careful that you don't mix up your own class and the [`System.IO.File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: `.BaseStream.CanRead` perhaps, although explicitly disposing/null would be better.

Comment: I'm French, so my class is "Fichier". I'll edit this, I wanted to be comprehensive but I did the opposite.

Comment: You just shouldn't design a FileStream wrapper that can Close and Reopen its stream. Keep it simpler. This probably is an XY problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest thing is to `Dispose` (you really should do that, it closes the stream too) it and set it to `null` when you close it.

Optionally you could check for `EndOfStream`, but that requires you to read to the end of the stream.

Comment: Good idea; thank you. Why should I prefer `Dispose` to `Close` ? (according this topic, `Close` calls `Dispose` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524903/should-i-call-close-or-dispose-for-stream-objects )

Comment: @Chostakovitch: Opinions vary, but my opinion is: if it implements `IDisposable`, call `Dispose`. That is future proof too, because when Microsoft updates it and it does require disposal then, you are safe.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the reference to null when you close the reader:

```
sr.Close();
sr = null;
```

There is no reason to hang on to the stream reader, as you can't reopen it. You have to create a new one to get an open stream reader.

Answer (score 3):

There is no public way to check if stream/reader is closed. Just set `reader` to null as soon as you closed it:

```
 Reader.Close();
 reader = null;
```

Or keep separate flag.

Comment: I had not though to that even it is simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader.Close()` will do a number of things if the `leaveOpen` flag is set to `false`, if that is the case then you could check if `StreamReader.BaseStream` is `null`.

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.xml");

var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
Console.WriteLine(streamReader.BaseStream == null);

streamReader.Close();
Console.WriteLine(streamReader.BaseStream == null);
```

outputs:

> False
>
> True
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't think this behavior is documented, so it would be better to not rely on it. Indeed if one have no control over when reader is disposed this may be an option. Additionally using `StreamReader` specific property will limit options to use other readers instead (i.e. base `TextReader`).