# Necessary to explicitly close a stream in c#

Tags: c#, stream

I've come across some code like so:

```
            using (StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                response = myStream.ReadToEnd();
                myStream.Close();   //Is this necessary?
            }
```

I don't think this .Close() statement is necessary.  My understanding is that the stream will close once we step out of the final brace of the using statement, right?

Comment: Correct, you don't need the explicit close. The using statement will call `Dispose()`, which calls `Close` internally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I call Close() or Dispose() for stream objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524903/should-i-call-close-or-dispose-for-stream-objects)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you don't need to close stream, this is benefit of using block.
Just need below lines only

```
using (StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            response = myStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

refer this link:
[What is the purpose of the Using block in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212198/what-is-the-c-sharp-using-block-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Instead of copying from another answer, you can vote to close this question as a duplicate of that other question (once you have enough rep)