# SerializeObject & StreamWriter created file not complete

Tags: c#, json, streamwriter

here is my code :

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stocksArticles,Formatting.Indented);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Export\\Stocks.json");
sw.Write(json);
```

it's working fine but the json file is not complete it's look like the StreamWriter stop before the end, this is the end of the file :

`{ "Reference": "999840", "Stocks": { "S": 0.0 } }, { "`

i dont understand why it's stopping, i tried to define the buffersize for the StreamWriter but no effect.

Comment: Sounds like you are not disposing something correctly, please show full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common sign of not flushing/closing the stream (it is quite common for streams to maintain some buffer for performance reasons). You can do something like:

```cs
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Export\\Stocks.json");
sw.Write(json);
sw.Close();
```

But far more correct approach is to use `using` which will dispose the resource correctly:

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Export\\Stocks.json"))
{
    sw.Write(json);
}
```

Read more:

- [Cleaning up unmanaged resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)
- [Using objects that implement `IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)
- [Should I call Close() or Dispose() for stream objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7524903/2501279)

Answer (score -1):

you don't need any stremwriter. just try this code

```
File.WriteAllText(@"Export\Stocks.json",json);
```

Comment: Arguably they *do* need one, because they should serialize directly to a stream rather than into a string

Comment: @Charlieface Is this serialized directly to  a stream string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stocksArticles,Formatting.Indented); ??? You should think at first and post a comment the second

Comment: No it isn't. But I said *should* not *did*: in other words they should instead still keep the writer so that they can serialize directly without going via a string.