# File-Stream is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream

```
FileStream f=new FileStream("c:\\file.xml",FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sf=new StreamWriter(f);
sf.WriteLine(stroka);
sf.Close();
sf.Dispose();
f.Close();
f.Dispose();
FileStream f1=new FileStream("c:\\file.xml",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("c:\\file.xml");
xmlreader=new XmlTextReader(sr);
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
f1.Close();
f1.Dispose();
```

I am getting this error:

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\file.xml' because it is being used by another process

I've closed all and disposed all. What's the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace:

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("c:\\file.xml");
```

With:

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(f1);
```

You're creating new `StreamReader` without the `FileStream`

---

**Additional data:**

- The `StreamReader` object calls `Dispose` on the provided Stream object when `StreamReader.Dispose` is called.
- `Dispose` method calls the `Close` method. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush) for more info.

Meaning: you can remove the `Dispose` and `Close` you wrote on the `FileStream`

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("c:\\file.xml", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sf = new StreamWriter(f);
sf.WriteLine(stroka);
sf.Dispose();

FileStream f1 = new FileStream("c:\\file.xml", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f1);
xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(sr);
sr.Dispose();
```

But you **really** should use the `using statement` for *unmanaged resources*, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: I had this problem , please note that you should 'Close' the stream before 'Disposing'

Comment: @Mironline. That is being done automatically. read **all** of my answer... you can see what is Dispose doing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/911431/601179)

Answer (score 2):

You have a FileStream and a StreamReader on the same file.
Remove this line:

```
FileStream f1=new FileStream("c:\\file.xml",FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("c:\\file.xml");
```

to

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(f1);
```

both of the followiong lines of code are separate objects trying to access the same file:

```
FileStream f1=new FileStream("c:\\file.xml",FileMode.Open); 
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("c:\\file.xml");
```

so each is attempting to access teh file indivodually, whereas changing your code to my connection cases sr to access the file Through f1

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be at:

```
FileStream f1=new FileStream("c:\\file.xml",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("c:\\file.xml");
```

Filestream may be accessing the file and then StreamReader tries to access the file separately. Try having your StreamReader use the same defined Stream.