# How to find whether a file is still being streamed?

Tags: c#, file, exception, io, stream

I am writing a small program to automatically change the desktop wallpaper, from an online image gallery (imgur). Currently I have this code:

```
namespace Imgur_Wallpapers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //IMGUR API = 3f1e4339e7bad35ff801bf76e369ae17

        private int Count = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            if (!File.Exists("image_black"))
            {
                Bitmap black = new Bitmap(10, 10);
                black.Save("transitionpaper.bmp");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadFromImgur download = new DownloadFromImgur("gjZEc", Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath));
            Wallpaper.Set(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "/Image.bmp"), Wallpaper.Style.Centered);
            Count++;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DownloadFromImgur download = new DownloadFromImgur(imgurAlbumIdBox.Text, Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath));

            Wallpaper.Set(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "/Image.bmp"), Wallpaper.Style.Centered);
            Count++;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = (int)whenToRefreshBox.Value;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

        private string url;
        public List<string> hash;
        private Random random;
        private string albumID;


        public DownloadFromImgur(string albumID, string folderToSaveTo)
        {
            try
            {
                this.albumID = albumID;
                hash = new List<string>();
                random = new Random();
                GetWebSite();
                Wallpaper.Set(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + "/transitionpaper.bmp"), Wallpaper.Style.Centered);
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/Image.bmp");
                client.DownloadFile(url, Application.StartupPath +  "/Image.bmp");
                client.Dispose();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void GetWebSite()
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load("http://api.imgur.com/2/album/" + albumID);

            hash.Clear();
            RecursiveWrite(doc.Root);

            url = hash[random.Next(hash.Count - 1)];
        }

        private void RecursiveWrite(XElement node)
        {
            foreach (var attribute  in node.Value)
            {
                if (node.Name == "original")
                {
                    hash.Add(node.Value);
                    break;
                }
            }

            foreach (var child in node.Elements())
            {
                RecursiveWrite(child);
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class Wallpaper
    {
        Wallpaper() { }

        const int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
        const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

        public enum Style : int
        {
            Tiled,
            Centered,
            Stretched
        }

        public static void Set(Uri uri, Style style)
        {
            System.IO.Stream s = new System.Net.WebClient().OpenRead(uri.ToString());

            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
            string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "wallpaper.bmp");
            img.Save(tempPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
            if (style == Style.Stretched)
            {
                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
            }

            if (style == Style.Centered)
            {
                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
            }

            if (style == Style.Tiled)
            {
                key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
                key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 1.ToString());
            }

            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
                0,
                tempPath,
                SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when on the first run, but returns an IOException on the second run. Apparently the file is still being used somewhere. How can I find where it's still used? Here's the exception message:

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled
>   Message=The process cannot
>   access the file 'C:\Users\David\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Imgur Wallpapers\Imgur Wallpapers\bin\Debug\Image.bmp'
>   because it is being used by another process.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)

Comment: You also don't use temp directories, but the running folder. Huge problem!

Comment: @ColeJohnson Am I misunderstanding your comment, or were you insulting the OP for using Windows Forms?

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's one opinion. It's completely irrelevant to the question, though.

Comment: @FelicePollano he shouldn't have to do that. Also if the file is still being used, he won't be able to delete it

Comment: @ColeJohnson - That is pure opinion.  I have a bigger problem that I have to go to a third-party site instead of view code on a website I know is safe.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I guess the file is in use because it is the current wallpapaer, but this would not explain why the first time it works, so you are probably correct.

Comment: @FelicePollano when windows sets a wallpaper, it saves It to a directory in the AppData, hence why you can set an image as the wallpaper and then delete it.

Comment: -1 to question: no code in the question. Please consider editing this question to include relevant code, for future questions please make sure to include code directly into the question, try to make code small enough so there is no scrolling required.

Comment: @ColeJohnson it's fine I removed the comment

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not using WPF. I'm still new to programming :D

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I put the code on pastie, seeing as it is 152 lines.

Comment: The problem with not pasting code is that external links can/will die and after that the question is no longer useful on this site. If you think your question is "too localized" to be useful for more than a day maybe you should see if there is broader one that should be asked instead to be useful for longer time. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code for discussion (covers HTML, but relevant for all languages) and this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73918/asking-a-question-with-lots-of-source-code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't close the download stream when it completes. If you don't, the stream is still hooked to the file. Try using .Close() and .Dispose()

Comment: It's still throwing the same exception.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, for CLR classes there is no need to use both Close and Dispose as you've suggested - for all relevant cases Close and calls Dispose do exactly the same thing. The reason Close is provided on Stream-based classes is to support natural Open-write/read-Close way of writing code, but `using(var s=new Stream...){}` is equivalent and often shorter/more C#-style code.

Comment: using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
    File.Delete("Image.bmp");
    client.DownloadFile(url, "Image.bmp");
    }

Comment: @ColeJohnson Disposing of a stream should close it too. See [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush)

Comment: @Bridge Disposing shouldn't be necessary when I am using a using block

Comment: @user1382827 I know - I was pointing out that despite what Cole said, a using block would both close and dispose of any resources for you.

Answer (score 1):

I always found this [tool](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html?tag=mncol;1) very helpful in figuring out what was locking which file.

I haven't used in a while but it is worth a shot.

Comment: he is probably his program to lock the file :)