# Destination file blank after writing with StreamWriter C#

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have written a console application that in itself is working as I would like it to. It's main output works great in console. But the results inside the loop I want written to a text file. I have used StreamWriter to attempt this and although I receive no errors on compilation or running, the file in my C: drive remains blank. Can anyone spot any stupid or quick things I have missed?

If you can help, thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Test.txt");
            double z = 0;
            double x = 1;
            double y = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("How many lines should be written to the file?");
            Console.WriteLine();
            z = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Writing " + z + "lines to file!");
            Console.WriteLine();

            while (z > 0)
            {
                y = Math.Pow(x, 2);
                Console.WriteLine(x + ", " + y*10);
                file.WriteLine(x + ", " + y*10);
                z = z - 1;
                x = x + 1;

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("**Generation Complete**");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("**Writing to file successful**");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            file.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaveDev, Jon Skeet and others. Thanks for the replies. At this point in time, I'm sure it's not a permissions issue as the file is being created. But when I open, it is blank. This includes using the 'using' statement. Any ideas?

**Ignore. Working fine now. Thank you so much everyone**

Comment: Any idea what was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had issues similar to this before. If I recall correctly, the solution came down to wrapping the StreamWriter in a using block, rather than creating it and then trying to close it, e.g.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Test.txt"))
        {
        double z = 0;
        double x = 1;
        double y = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("How many lines should be written to the file?");
        Console.WriteLine();
        z = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Writing " + z + "lines to file!");
        Console.WriteLine();

        while (z > 0)
        {
            y = Math.Pow(x, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(x + ", " + y*10);
            file.WriteLine(x + ", " + y*10);
            z = z - 1;
            x = x + 1;

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("**Generation Complete**");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("**Writing to file successful**");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
```

Comment: If the code is running without exceptions, then adding a `using` statement wouldn't help. It's still a good idea, but it doesn't explain why they OP was seeing a blank file, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `using` statament for everything that implements `IDisposable` like the `StreamWriter`. This will ensure that unmanaged resources are disposed (**even on error**). It'll also flush the stream if it's [`AutoFlush` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) is `false`(default).

```
using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\Test.txt"))
{
    // ...
    file.WriteLine(x + ", " + y*10);
    // rest of code here ...
}
```

[Does Stream.Dispose always call Stream.Close (and Stream.Flush)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush)

Answer (score 2):

When I run that code, I see an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
Access to the path 'c:\Test.txt' is denied.
```

It's not clear how you're running this, but if it's configured as a console app and you run it from a console window so you'll definitely see any exceptions, I suspect you'll see the same thing.

Try changing it to write to somewhere you definitely have access to - and also try to work out why you didn't see the exception before.

Additionally it would definitely be better to use a `using` statement as other answers have shown - but that wouldn't explain a clean run (no exceptions) without the file being created.

Comment: Thanks, please see my reply above :)