# Unable to open a file/directory containing Spaces in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating windows form application.
I am unable to put the output in a file. The issue is that there is space in the path name.

I want to create a file name and write the file at below location.

C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\details.txt

Please help.

Below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String val_input_file_name = textBox1.Text;

        MessageBox.Show(val_input_file_name);
        try
        {

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(val_input_file_name);
            file.WriteLine("Testing done" + val_input_file_name);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Spaces shouldn't be an issue. Maybe permissions?

Comment: you are not closing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `StreamWriter` object with a `using` statement:

```
using(var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(val_input_file_name))
{
    file.WriteLine("Testing done" + val_input_file_name);
}
```

Comment: Other than closing the stream and releasing the file, what will this do?

Comment: I believe not closing the stream is the _actual_ problem. that's why the content is not written to the file..

Comment: Ok, so the dispose method must call a `flush()`, which will do the actual writing to the file.

Comment: [yes exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush)

Comment: Thanks I believe i did not close the file...Appologies for the silly question.