# How can you disregard the buffer of a streamwriter

Tags: c#, file, stream, streamwriter

I am using a streamwriter to write to a file stream like so

```
using(StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText('MyFile.csv'))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Header1,Header2")

    //Write multiple lines based on some logic
    DoSomeOtherThings(writer)

    writer.Flush();
}
```

If my application errors in the middle of writing, I do not want to write to the file at all. To do this I thought I would just not have to flush until the end. However even if there is an error any data that was writing is saved to my file.

Is there a way to disregard the buffer of the StreamWriter so It does not save the data to the file unless it reaches the end of the logic?

Comment: Clearly you've destroyed the file no matter what you do so you'll need to delete it.  Or not append it.  Or use a StringWriter instead.

Comment: Have DoSomeOtherThings write to a memory buffer and if it doesn't fail then write that memory buffer to the file.

Comment: Would wrapping the logic in a try catch and closing the base stream (the file stream in this case) in the catch section be a reasonable option? This would close the stream before the writer has a chance to flush the data

Answer (score 0):

Flush gets called in the Dispose method of the StreamWriter.  See [Does Stream.Dispose always call Stream.Close (and Stream.Flush)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush)  for instance.  And Dispose gets called even if an error has occurred when using the 'using' construct.

Comment: Does it also get called in the finalizer when it is garbage collected? If not could I simply remove the using statement so it does not get disposed.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this but it looks like there is a AutoFlush property on the [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You might be able to set that to false right after you create the writer and it might do what you want.