# Do I need to close a SqlDataReader before I call Dispose on it?

Tags: ado.net, garbage-collection

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call/61096#61096), **Dispose()** on a **SqlConnection** calls **Close()**, so you don't need to call both, just **Dispose()**. Is it the same for a **SqlDataReader**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to call **Dispose** because calls **Close**.

I used [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and found that **DbDataReader's** (the base of **SqlDataReader**) **Dispose** method does call **Close**.