# What is the difference between Dispose and Close?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close and Dispose - which to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call)

Hi,

After reading some web pages, I still don't understand the difference between Dispose and Close methods in C#.

Let's take a sample:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    // Execute an insert statement (no breaks, exceptions, returns, etc.)
}
```

and a second one:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
// Execute an insert statement (no breaks, exceptions, returns, etc.)
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Are those two pieces of code similar? Are both available only for convenience (since there are situations where `using` is not a solution? Or there is a difference in the behavior?

So why some classes provide `Close` method and when should I put a `Close` method in `IDisposable` classes I create?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call

Comment: Thanks to note that it is a duplicate. I searched before posting, but didn't found it. I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two code snippets are equivalent.

.NET classes that implement `IDisposable` and expose `Close`, do it juts for the added convenience of having a `Close` method that has a slightly friendlier name. Typically one calls the other.

If you implement your own disposable class, you won't need to add a `Close` method, unless you like to have one.

Comment: This is almost correct. `Dispose` and `Close` are the same *except* for database connection classes.