# close or dispose

Tags: c#, .net

StreamReader class has both close and dispose method.  I want to know which method to call to clean up all resources.

If making use of using block, I think it will call its dispose method. Will it be enough to clean up all the resources.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/61092/102112

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `using` block will call `Dispose()` on the `StreamReader` instance. Generally speaking, if a type is `IDisposable`, you should put it in `using` scope.

**EDIT:**
If you look at the `Close()` implementation of `StreamReader` using Reflector, you will see that it's calling `Dispose(true)`. So if you're not using the `using` scope, calling `Close()` manually would be the same as calling `Dispose()` in this particular case.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if ((this.Closable && disposing) && (this.stream != null))
        {
            this.stream.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (this.Closable && (this.stream != null))
        {
            this.stream = null;
            this.encoding = null;
            this.decoder = null;
            this.byteBuffer = null;
            this.charBuffer = null;
            this.charPos = 0;
            this.charLen = 0;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: close calls dispose(true), will using block also call dispose(true)?

Comment: This explains why if you have code inside a `using` with a call to `Close()`,  upon running Visual Studio's Code Analysis you will get `CA2202 Do not dispose objects multiple times` - because `Close()` already disposes, and `using` will eventually try disposing the object, again. I wonder, then... why we do not really face `System.ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @Veverke, Close disposes the object but does not mark as disposed that is why it doesn't throw  System.ObjectDisposedException.

Answer (score 7):

We all know `System.IO.StreamReader` is not the only .NET 4.0+ class that implements `IDisposable` and a `Close()` method. For the case of `StreamReader` in this question, the source code shows that the base class [`TextReader.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,70), [`TextReader.Dispose()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,76)  both run the same lines of code. You can also see in the code that `TextReader.Dispose()` is the implementation for when you call `StreamReader.Dispose()` (because `StreamReader` doesn't override that method overload signature of `Dispose`).

So a call to `StreamReader.Dispose()` will run [this inherited line of code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs,78), which calls the protected override method [`StreamReader.Dispose(disposing: true)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,288) and so will [`StreamReader.Close()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,283) call `StreamReader.Dispose(disposing: true)`. So for the case of `StreamReader`, `Close()` and `Dispose()` do happen to run the same lines of code.

A more general, non-class-specific answer to the question of *Close() or Dispose()?*, might be to note that Microsoft has fairly clear [documentation on implementing `IDisposable` and the Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx). A quick read is enough to show you that implementing a `Close()` method is not a requirement of the Dispose pattern.

imho the reason for finding the method `Close()` on so many classes that implement `IDisposable`, is the result of convention, not requirement.

Someone commented

> [Close and Dispose - which to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61092/102112)

An example of another class that implements `IDisposable` with the Dispose pattern, and has a `Close()` method. Does `Close()` run the same code as `Dispose()` in this case? I haven't looked at the source code, but I'd say not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dispose via a using block to guarantee that clean-up happens.

Use Close if you finish with the object considerably before the end of the using block, to be as prompt as possible in releasing any resources.

The two will hence work hand-in-hand, though the latter can be redundant if you are going to reach the end of the block in a few nanoseconds anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The using block is all that you need.

Comment: Using will guarantee to call dispose. Is it same as calling close?

Comment: dispose will implicit close the stream

Comment: ...unless you write "complex" code with long-lived objects.  Better advice would be: use using if syntactically possible. Else handle the complexity that the programming world dealt with since the invention of memory allocation like a big kid--carefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you want further information about `using`, take a look here

[Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Quote from site:

> The using statement allows the
>   programmer to specify when objects
>   that use resources should release
>   them. The object provided to the using
>   statement must implement the
>   IDisposable interface. This interface
>   provides the Dispose method, which
>   should release the object's resources.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some concern about whether `Dispose` actually does its job properly.

Essentially - **you can be fairly certain that anything in the BCL(Base Class Library) which implements `IDisposable` will tidy itself up properly when dispose is called** - such as when a using statement goes out of scope.

If there were issues with streams not being closed they would have been picked up by now - you can trust `IDisposable`. It's when you're using other libraries that you rely on the `Dispose` implementation.