# Cleaning Up Resources via Using Statement & Dispose for DataTable, SqlConnection, SqlCommand, & SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net, resources, using, sqlclient

I have to call a stored procedure and get the results.  I know there are various ways of doing this (as with all programming), and that I should be cleaning up the resources by calling `Dispose()` and/or `Close()`.  Reading this [close or dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153595/close-or-dispose) question I'm thinking that I should be using the `using` statement and that should be enough.  Below is how I'm making my call.  My question is - am I over complicating this and will this clean up all of the resources?

```
private Int32 CallStoredProcedure(Int32 Id)
{
    using (var dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SEL_StoredProcedure", conn))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);
                    sqlCmd.Connection.Open();

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            return Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["IDv2"]);
        else if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            throw new Exception("Multiple records were found with supplied ID; ID = " + studentId.ToString());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. - I know I could call `ExecuteScalar`, but that's not what I'm looking for here since I will be using the general format for non-scalar calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you wrote does appear to dispose all objects properly.

What you should be aware of is that disposing a DataTable makes that object unusable, which is not *usually* the intent with a DataTable.  Typically if you are populating a DataTable you intend to keep the data around (cached) for a while, and not discard it within the query method.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you do not need to wrap the DataTable or the SqlDataAdapter in using blocks, as they do not implement IDisposable.

You can "chain" the using statements toegether like this:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SEL_storedProcedure", conn))
{

}
```

Comment: Yes they do.  They inherit `MarshalByValueComponent` and `Component` respectively, which are disposable.

Comment: the chaining is interesting and will remove many of the braces.  Chris is right though, and they both have a `Dispose()` method in intellisense :-)

Comment: good to know, thanks. I've very rarely seen DataTable wrapped in using (and very rarely done it myself) or disposed of after use.

Comment: @RobinHames if you're interested, there's a Code Analysis check to make sure `Dispose()` is called everywhere it is necessary.  CA1063.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx