# Passing Integer values to SqlParameter in .net

Tags: asp.net, sqldatareader, sqlparameter

i want to pass integer value to the SqlParameter which is executing an SqlDataReader, but when i pass integer value it says, the Parameter is not supplied, below is my code:

```
Common SqlDataReader Function

public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string procedure, SqlParameter[] parameters, CommandType commandType)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                if (commandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

Calling code:

```
SqlDataReader obj = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader("sp_TheWireUser", new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@USERID", Convert.ToInt32(1)), new SqlParameter("@ROLEID", Convert.ToInt32(6)) }, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        Response.Write(obj.HasRows);
```

i tried entering `1` as a parameter also `"1"` but all does not work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TheWireUser]
    @USERID INT,
    @RoleID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT USR.USERID FROM Users USR
    INNER JOIN UserRoles UR
    ON USR.UserID = UR.UserID
    INNER JOIN Roles R
    ON UR.RoleID = R.RoleID
    WHERE R.RoleID = @RoleID
    AND USR.UserID = @USERID
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting `1` to Integer by calling Convert.ToInt32() .`1` is already integer. So you do not need to do that.

```
SqlDataReader obj = ExecuteReader("sp_TheWireUser", 
                new SqlParameter[] { 
                    new SqlParameter("@USERID", 1),
                    new SqlParameter("@ROLEID", 6)
                },
                System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This code should not throw any compile time errors. If you are getting a runtime exception, The possible reason is your Stored Procs paramter's ***data type is different*** than what you are passing here. It should be `Integer` as per your code.

*Note : Hope you are closing the `DataReader` after use.*

**EDIT :** You have to tell the **`CommandType`**

```
 using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
 {
    command.CommandType = commandType; //passed from your method parameter
    //your remaining code
 }
```

Comment: hi @Shyju i have updated my question to also include my Stored Procedure, i also passed value without converting that too does not work

Comment: Are you getting the exception when you hard code the values (1 and 6) ?

Comment: yes, i gets the message with hardcode values as well as dynamic values

Comment: i am passing the commandType in my calling code...
System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: @Abbas:Yes. But **you have to Set the CommandType Property value** of the command object you are executing. Add that line and it will work. I tested it

Comment: Thanks @Shyju that helped me to resolved my issue thanks a lot, May God bless you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a similar question I asked in the past.  [Cleaning Up Resources via Using Statement & Dispose for DataTable, SqlConnection, SqlCommand, & SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158602/cleaning-up-resources-via-using-statement-dispose-for-datatable-sqlconnection)

It will show you how to clean up your data and also how to add a parameter.  Also, wait until the last minute to Open your connection, i.e., add the parameter first.