# How to dispose of a System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>?

Tags: idisposable

I'm using a class that extends ClientBase<>:

```
interface IService {}
class MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IService> {}
```

The issue I run into is that FxCop complains that a class with MyServiceClient as a member variable should also implement IDisposable and dispose of MyServiceClient.

[ClientBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576143%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) has an explicit implementation of Dispose(), which means a simple MyServiceClient.Dispose() doesn't compile.  I have to explicitly cast to IDisposable.  Why is that?  Is it a signal that I shouldn't use Dispose()?  Should I use Close() instead?

Answer (score 4):

In [Close and Dispose - which to call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call) is suggested that Close and Dispose should have the same implementation. [Here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx) is an example wrapper class ([usage](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2007/01/30/usage-of-the-wcf-serviceproxyhelper.aspx)) which calls Close in the Dispose function. So it seems fine to call Close.

Answer (score 0):

I wraped my Base inheritor in using bloc and it works. Like this:

```
using (var someClient = new SomeClient(_netTcpBinding,_endpointAddress))
{
    return someClient.SomeMethod();
}
```

But when i open cmd and enter  netstat -a -n -p TCP i saw 
[image]

The answer I found here http://sahilmalik.blogspot.ru/2005/11/sockets-and-timewait.html
and I rewrote my code like in this case http://marcgravell.blogspot.ru/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html