# What is the difference between connection.Close() and connection.Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net, system.data.sqlite

I noticed that the `SQLiteConnection` object in `System.Data.SQLite` owns two similar methods :

- `Close()`
- `Dispose()`

Same for the `SQLiteDataReader` object.

What is the difference ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see this post !

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Dispose` also closes the connection if it hasn't been closed, but when calling `Close`, you can reopen the connection again. This is not possible when the connection is disposed.

In general, don't call `Close`, but simply call dispose implicitly by wrapping the creation of a connection in a `using` block:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // use connection here. e.g.:
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        ...
    }
} // connection gets closed and disposed here.
```

Comment: Taking a look at the [source](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/31b823606b81d72d120bdd8dca8de8421b9abb16) ...can show that `Dispose()` calls `Close()` internally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (sorry for the duplicate)

Comment: @Steven did I say it was?

Answer (score 8):

Connection.Close() will simply close the connection to the server as defined in the connection string. The Connection can be used/re-opened after this point.

`Connection.Dispose()` will clean up completely, removing all unmanaged resources preventing that Connection from being used again. Once disposed is called you shouldn't try to use the object any more. Within `Dispose(),`Close()` will all most certainly be called too.

I would recommend `using` the using syntax like so if possible, to ensure things are cleaned up correctly:

```
using(SqlLiteConnection conn = new SqlLiteConnection(...))
{
   // Do work here
}
```

This will automatically dispose of the connection for you, regardless of an exception being thrown.

Comment: One subtle difference is `Close` will not call the `GC.SuppressFinalize` method on that connection, while `Dispose` does call that method. Not disposing a connection will therefore keep the connection object alive for much longer. This has no effect on the connection pool, but does have on memory. The difference -in case of a `SqlConnection`- will however be neglectable.

Comment: Thanks, it's more clear for me now (sorry for the duplicate)