# Close connection in sql - Timeout

Tags: .net

I have a big issue that one of my sites is failing to load most times. Unfortunately i cannot upload pictures yet. The problem states the following

> The time out period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occured because all pooled connections where in use and max pool size was reached.

And i get a highlighted Line 14: upcmd.Connection.Open(). The error continues further.

I am not an expert at all so what i did so far from researching around what to add the Max Pool Size in    `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=yianniscy.db.7015338.hostedresource.com;initial catalog=xxxxxxx;User id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;**Max Pool Size=100**" />` in webconfig

The problem still remains although this application is used by a single person and never had this issue before. This started as soon as my hosting provider did an upgrade. At the moment i understand that connections remain open and need to be closed. The problem is that i have no idea what to put and where to put it. If someone can guide me where exactly and what exactly to put i would appreciate it.

```
Partial Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    Using upcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM Xuser_tab WHERE name=@logname", conn)

        upcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Login_name", TextBox1.Text))
        upcmd.Connection.Open()
        Dim password_temp As String

        Try
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = upcmd.ExecuteReader()

            If dr.Read Then
                password_temp = dr.Item(0)

                If password_temp = TextBox2.Text Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/Controlpanel.aspx")

                Else


                End If
                Image2.Visible = True
                Label1.Visible = True

            End If
```

Comment: Could you show some code where you are using the connection?

Comment: Hi @Molt Line 13 - upcmd.Parameters.Add(New SQL Parameter("@Login_name", Textbox1.Text)) Line 14 - upcmd.Connection.Open()     Line 15 Dim password_temp as String.    The error happens right after the user login in

Comment: do you have a `upcmd.Connection.Close()` when you are done with the query? If you don't close the connection your pool gets empty fast.

Comment: Need to show all of Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click.  Are you closing the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Using` disposes the object after `End Using` so the connection will be closed when leaving this construct.

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
      Using upcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT login FROM Xuser_tab WHERE name=@logname", conn)

        // @logname != @Login_name..
        upcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Login_name", TextBox1.Text)) 
        upcmd.Connection.Open()
        Dim password_temp As String

        Try
           Dim dr As SqlDataReader = upcmd.ExecuteReader()

           If dr.Read Then

           // code omitted

        End Using
conn.Close() // Optional
End Using
// Here will conn be disposed and connection closed
```

[An explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171/1764737) of the differences between `Close()` and `Dispose()`. `Dispose()` is the method being called behind the scenes at `End Using`.

Comment: sorry please see above for the code. where should i close the connection exactly?

Comment: i got it . it was simple. good thing i checked because i had to close the connection in many places. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the problem is in your code, check the following:

- are connection closed?
- are you using usings around database connection objects?
- how is your error handling and connection closing?

For a single user website you do not need a large connection pool, you normally use only one connection at once. With some code we can be more specific.

Comment: Regarding your 1st point i think i am not closing the connections. This is based on my research and the error code. the problem is that i dont know how to close the connection or where to put the code. The above code i mentioned is not helpful? thank you

Comment: should i be using both conn.close() and upcmd.connection.close()

Comment: @VivereestVincere Just disposing the connection is good enough, you only need to call `Close()` if you plan on calling other methods after closing the object, if you are done just let it be disposed by wrapping it in a using block.