# Saving an image using FileStream sometimes results in corrupt files

Tags: c#, filestream, corruption, bitmapsource, jpegbitmapencoder

I have an application where by I take a picture and press a save button and save the image to the computer. This works fine the majority of the time. But I am seeing some of my users with corrupt images. These images are about the right number of bytes in size but when trying to the bytes for the image it is just a load of null values.

My code for saving the photos is:

```
try
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(localCopyFileLocation, FileMode.Create))
    {
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.QualityLevel = quality;
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(photo, null, metadata, null));
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Write to log etc.
}
```

From [FileStream Constructor (SafeFileHandle, FileAccess)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fz1x84(v=vs.110).aspx) I read this:

> When Close is called, the handle is also closed and the file's handle
>   count is decremented.
>
> FileStream assumes that it has exclusive control
>   over the handle. Reading, writing, or seeking while a FileStream is
>   also holding a handle could result in data corruption. For data
>   safety, call Flush before using the handle, and avoid calling any
>   methods other than Close after you are done using the handle.

But I am unsure what this means? Could my users be putting their tablets to sleep while writing the file? What other reasons could it be that this is happening?

Comment: It sounds like you need to call `stream.Flush();` after the call to `save()`

Comment: Why would I need to call `steam.Flush()`? What does that call do?

Comment: Do you have the right constructor documentation? It looks like you're using this [FileStream Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092/close-and-dispose-which-to-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify - you need to call [`Flush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Calling `Close()` is not enough. `Close()` calls `Dispose()` which does the following

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if (this._handle != null && !this._handle.IsClosed && this._writePos > 0)
        {
            this.FlushWrite(!disposing);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (this._handle != null && !this._handle.IsClosed)
        {
            this._handle.Dispose();
        }
        this._canRead = false;
        this._canWrite = false;
        this._canSeek = false;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, here is what `Flush()` does:

```
public override void Flush()
{
    this.Flush(false);
}
```

Which calls:

```
public virtual void Flush(bool flushToDisk)
{
    if (this._handle.IsClosed)
    {
        __Error.FileNotOpen();
    }
    this.FlushInternalBuffer();
    if (flushToDisk && this.CanWrite)
    {
        this.FlushOSBuffer();
    }
}
```

The key (I think, but I'm not certain) is `FlushOSBuffer()`

```
private void FlushOSBuffer()
{
    if (!Win32Native.FlushFileBuffers(this._handle))
    {
        __Error.WinIOError();
    }
}
```

If calling `Flush()` does not work, than try the override `Flush(true)` which will result in the Win32 API [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) being called, which will flush intermediate file buffers.

Comment: So from what you're saying. I need to call `Flush(true)`?

Comment: Yes you cant try that, see what happens. Either way, you need to call one of the `Flush()` methods in order to ensure that the file buffers are emptied.

Comment: I'm unsure whether this solved my issue as it is quite a difficult thing to test as it seems to happen randomly. But this answer makes most sense from what I am reading

Comment: Yeah it's going to be trial and error by the sounds of it. But in general, calling `Flush()` for file related I/O code is a common practice. Hope this helps you.