# Best way to do connection management in dapper?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core, dapper

I am using the following way of querying in dapper on a `MySQL` database.

```cs
using (var db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationHandler.GetSection<string>(StringConstants.ConnectionString)))
{
    resultSet = db.Execute(UpdateQuery, new { _val = terminalId }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
    db.Close();//should i call this or not
    db.Dispose();//should i call this or not
}
```

Is it a good way of explicitly calling db.close and db.dispose? My application could be handling 100's of requests per second.

Comment: You don't need either the `Close` or `Dispose`. The `using` will call `Dispose` for you already.

Comment: What is the type of `resultSet`?

Comment: resultSet are different at different points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A using block is a convenience arround the `IDisposable` interface. It ensures that the dispose method is called at the end of the block.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement.

In your case you can remove the explicit calls to db.Close() and db.Dispose() because you are not re-using the connection object.

```
using (var db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationHandler.GetSection<string>(StringConstants.ConnectionString)))
                {
                    resultSet = db.Execute(UpdateQuery,
                        new { _val = terminalId }, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                }
```

The following link provides further details about .Close vs .Dispose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171/1028323

Comment: Also, if your database driver (read: nuget package for mysql) supports connection pooling, then this practice will allow your app_pool to re-open the connection within a timespan without having to re-connect. -- which is handy and performant.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Jason. I am doing exactly like this with about 100 connections in pool