# Display all values stored in a column to a label?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a table called `T_Score` and the column called `Team1`, it has some stored values and I want these values to be added and displayed on a label.

This is the code which stores the values in the table:

```cs
private void Btn_LeaderB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new LeaderBoard());

    SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-S2J1U9SJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Unit4_IT;Integrated Security=True");

    conne.Open();
    string insertQuery = "insert into T_Score(Team1) " +
         "values(@Team1)";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conne);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team1", txt_score4_tm1.Text);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conne.Close();
}
```

This code stores the value that needs to be added with the previous value.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Twenty i  dont know how to really approach it but im guessing SUM needs to be used.

Comment: It would help if we would have the datatypes of the values as well.

Comment: You need to 1) add the values, 2) return data from the database and 3) display it in a label. (1 & 2 could be done in either order). Which bit is causing you difficulty?

Comment: @Twenty Its intergers.

Comment: @RobinBennett whats causing me difficulty is know how to add the int values and then displaying the total.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - FYI `add` isn't the correct word in this context `1 + 2 = 3` doesn't mean `one add two equals three` it would be `one plus two equals three` and if you want to say you want to `add` any numbers together you are saying `sum up` or `build a sum` or `sum of` instead - so your last sentence should be `... is know how to sum int values ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query `select sum(Team1) from T_Score;` and instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` use `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` and use the return value of the method `ExecuteScalar`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar

Like this:

```
private void WriteToLabel()
{    
    using (SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-S2J1U9SJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Unit4_IT;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conne.Open();
        string selectQuery = "select sum(Team1) from T_Score;";
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conne))
            label1.Content = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

The line

```
label1.Content = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Will require a `Label` called `label1` for it to work.
It tries to write the result of `Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar())` into the `Content` property of said `Label`.

You can also use a `TextBlock` and than use the `Text` Property, so this line:

```
textBlock1.Text = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Notice instead of calling `conne.Close();` manually, I wrapped the `SqlConnection conne` into a `using` Statement, this should always be done with objects that inherit from `IDisposable`.

You can read about `IDisposable` and the `using` statement here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61131/2598770

---

If you have the values already in a `IEnumerable` object eg. `List<int>` than you can just do the following

With a simple loop:

```
var myValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //<- list with temporary data
var sumOfValue = 0;
foreach (var myValue in myValues)
     sumOfValue += myValue;
```

With `LINQ`:

```
var myValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //<- list with temporary data
var sumOfValue = myValues.Sum();
```

If you don't have an `IEnumerable` of `int` but instead a `class` than your code will look like this

```
public class MyValue
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    //other properties
}

var myValues = new List<MyValue>() 
               { 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 1 }, 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 2 }, 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 3 }, 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 4 }, 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 5 }, 
                   new MyValue() { Value = 6 }, 
               }; //<- list with temporary data
```

With a simple loop:

```
var sumOfValue = 0;
foreach (var myValue in myValues)
     sumOfValue += myValue.Value;
```

With `LINQ`:

```
var sumOfValue = myValues.Sum(x => x.Value);
```

In all those cases you will have to write `sumOfValue` into your `Label` or `TextBlock` like this

```
//Label
label1.Content = sumOfValue.ToString();
//or TextBlock
textBlock1.Text = sumOfValue.ToString();
```

---

To pass a value to a different page, all you would need to do is the following.

Search for your page in code behind eg. `LeaderBoard`.
It should look something like this

```
public partial class LeaderBoard : Page
{
    //stuff...
}
```

Add a new Property to this class

```
public partial class LeaderBoard : Page
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    //stuff...
}
```

When you initialize the `LeaderBoard` eg. here

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new LeaderBoard());
```

Change the initialization to this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, });
```

`7187` is a random number this needs to be filled with what ever you need.

With this you have "transfered" data to `LeaderBoard` and the new property with its value can be accessed in `LeaderBoard` eg. there could be a method like this

```
public void Foo()
{
    textBlock1.Text = Convert.ToString(this.MyProperty);
}
```

The class would than look like this:

```
public partial class LeaderBoard : Page
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    //stuff...

    public void Foo()
    {
        textBlock1.Text = Convert.ToString(this.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

If you need to change the `MyProperty` from a different place while the `LeaderBoard` is open keep the reference you have created.

To keep the reference change this line

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, });
```

To this

```
_leaderBoard = new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, };
this.NavigationService.Navigate(_leaderBoard);
```

And create a `Field` in the outer scope like this

```
private LeaderBoard _leaderBoard; //<- needs to be outside the method

private void Btn_LeaderB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _leaderBoard = new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, };
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(_leaderBoard);
}
```

If `Btn_LeaderB_Click` gets called multiple times but you only want to create 1 LeaderBoard you can do this:

```
private void Btn_LeaderB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_leaderBoard == null)
        _leaderBoard = new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, };

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(_leaderBoard);
}
```

With that the `_leaderBoard` field will only get initialized once.
If you want to increase the value `MyProperty` everytime the `Btn_LeaderB_Click` method gets called you can further extend it to this:

```
private void Btn_LeaderB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_leaderBoard == null)
        _leaderBoard = new LeaderBoard() { MyProperty = 7187, };
    else
        _leaderBoard.MyProperty += int.Parse(txt_score4_tm1.Text);

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(_leaderBoard);
}
```

Comment: Why is Text giving me an error and insertQuery or am i suppose change that

Comment: is insertquery suppose to be selectquery

Comment: it almost works it just doesnt plus the values in the column.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - edited my answer to clarify `label1.Text` and fixed the copy & paste error with `insertQuery`.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - about your problem that my code doesn't produce a sum, this can't be the case since `sum(Team1)` in the `SQL` query, will sum all values in the `Team1` column. Make sure the correct values are in the database. Eg. use SQL Server Management Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) to connect to your database and have a look what values are in your table `T_Score`

Comment: I just used a textbloxk that fixed that issue however it still doesnt return the correct sum i will check again.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - if you need further assistance you will have to provide more information, like what data is in the table? what sum does the current code produce? what is your expected result? - good luck

Comment: i was thinking maybe this could be easier done without the database and use classes instead for example, have a class where it stores the text box values and then uses thos numbers to just simply add them and display them - dont know if that makes any sense.

Comment: I might just be over complicating it by using a database

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - Can't really give an answer to this, since I don't know the greater picture. I updated my answer to show you how to build a sum if you have the values stored in a list.

Comment: my brain cells are melting. Is the new updated asnwer without a database because all im trying to do is store an int and then use it on a different page to create a total.

Comment: i need to access the stored int on a different page basically.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - The new updated answer does not require a database, BUT the main difference is how it gets stored. If you store it in the database it will be "permamently" the new answer is only stored in memory. I don't know your requirement if the value needs to be stored beyond the app life cycle, so if you re-open the app if the value should still be available or gone. If it needs to be available you will need to write the value into a storage eg. DataBase.

Comment: It does not need to be available it would be better if its gone.

Comment: what i tried is this ` int Score4;
            Score4 = int.Parse(txt_score4_tm1.Text);` but obviously this dosent allow me to use the value on a different page.

Comment: okay but  the value has to be able to change on button click this is why i have the textbox where to enter the value and then store it when button is clicked. However ill try the new updated answer.

Comment: @MarkMihailovs - updated once more and the last time for today :)

Comment: `MyProperty = int.Parse(txt_score4_tm1.Text)` would this not technically store the enterd value and then show it.

Comment: It wont show the value by itself the property `Score` needs to be written into the User Interface eg. TextBlock / Label either manually by somewhere calling `textBlock1.Text = Score.ToString();` or by using a `Binding`.