# Exception in "using" statement with WCF not closing connections properly. How does one close faulted WCF client connections or those with exceptions?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, proxy, using-statement

There are several questions on StackOverflow regarding closing WCF connections, however the highest ranking answers refers to this blog:

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html

I have a problem with this technique when I set a breakpoint at the server and let the client hang for more than one minute.  (I'm intentionally creating a timeout exception)

The issue is that the client appears to "hang" until the server is done processing.  My guess is that everything is being cleaned up post-exception.

In regard to the `TimeOutException` it appears that the `retry()` logic of the client will continue to resubmit the query to the server over and over again, where I can see the server-side debugger queue up the requests **and then execute each queued request concurrently**.  My code wan't expecting WCF to act this way and may be the cause of data corruption issues I'm seeing.

Something doesn't totally add up with this solution.

> What is the all-encompassing modern way
>   of dealing with faults and exceptions
>   in a WCF proxy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Admittedly, this is a bit of mundane code to write.  [I currently prefer this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573872/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-wcf-client-using-block-issue/9370880#9370880), and don't see any "hacks" in that code that may cause issues down the road.

---

This is Microsoft's recommended way to handle WCF client calls:

For more detail see: [Expected Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354510.aspx)

```
try
{
    ...
    double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
    ...
    client.Close();
}
catch (TimeoutException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
    client.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", exception.GetType());
    client.Abort();
}
```

**Additional information**
So many people seem to be asking this question on WCF that Microsoft even created a dedicated sample to demonstrate how to handle exceptions:

c:\WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Basic\Client\ExpectedExceptions\CS\client

Download the sample:
[C#](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en) or  [VB](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vb2010samples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4174)

Considering that there are so many issues [involving the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx), [(heated?) Internal discussions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4cdc67e0-3069-4d3b-b94f-27e2b8ff4429/) and [threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/b95b91c7-d498-446c-b38f-ef132989c154/) on this issue, I'm not going to waste my time trying to become a code cowboy and find a cleaner way.  I'll just suck it up, and implement WCF clients this verbose (yet trusted) way for my server applications.

**Optional Additional Failures to catch**

Many exceptions derive from `CommunicationException` and I don't think most of those exceptions should be retried.  I drudged through each exception on MSDN and found a short list of retry-able exceptions (in addition to `TimeOutException` above). Do let me know if I missed an exception that should be retried.

```
Exception   mostRecentEx = null;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)  // Attempt a maximum of 5 times 
{
    try
    {
       ...
       double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
       ...
       client.Close();
    }

    // The following is typically thrown on the client when a channel is terminated due to the server closing the connection.
    catch (ChannelTerminatedException cte)
    {

      mostRecentEx = cte;
      secureSecretService.Abort();
        //  delay (backoff) and retry 
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * (i + 1)); 
    }

    // The following is thrown when a remote endpoint could not be found or reached.  The endpoint may not be found or 
    // reachable because the remote endpoint is down, the remote endpoint is unreachable, or because the remote network is unreachable.
    catch (EndpointNotFoundException enfe)
    {

      mostRecentEx = enfe;
     secureSecretService.Abort();
        //  delay (backoff) and retry 
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * (i + 1)); 
    }

    // The following exception that is thrown when a server is too busy to accept a message.
    catch (ServerTooBusyException stbe)
    {
      mostRecentEx = stbe;
        secureSecretService.Abort();

        //  delay (backoff) and retry 
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * (i + 1)); 
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
         throw ex;  // rethrow any other exception not defined here
    }
}
if (mostRecentEx != null) 
{
    throw new Exception("WCF call failed after 5 retries.", mostRecentEx );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Closing and Disposing a WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867/closing-and-disposing-a-wcf-service)

As that post alludes to, you Close when there were no exceptions and you Abort when there are errors.  `Dispose` and thus `Using` shouldn't be used with WCF.

Comment: Based on the links in that question it sure seems to me that the WCF stuff shouldn't have implemented IDisposable, but instead should have had a completely different architecture for cleanup.

Comment: @Chris Lively Indeed, it seems that everyone is trying to hack together a `using` statement going against Microsoft's recommendations.  MSFT's private internal discussions apparently want production applications to have a specific structured exception handling.  It will be verbose and annoying, but suppose I need to suck it up.

Comment: I can't find the link at the moment but I saw a site where someone had used lambdas to mask this behavior in a pretty interesting way.  It made the code far more palettable.  If I run into it again I'll post the link.

Comment: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/erwyn/archive/2006/12/09/WCF-Service-Proxy-Helper.aspx  This isn't the page I was thinking of, but it's a nice template class to help with the problem.  It also links to the MSDN forum where a MSFT dev talks about it.