# Properly Avoid ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, exception, objectdisposedexception

I ran into an issue where an `ObjectDisposedException` is being thrown roughly 50% of the time. The code within the `try` (within the `finally`) below, is causing the exception. I'm not sure how to handle this. I could just eat the exception, like shown below, but is there a way to check and close the object without the exception happening?

```
    public static FindResponse Discover(FindCriteria findCriteria, 
                                        DiscoveryEndpoint discoveryEndpoint = null)
    {
        DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = null;

        try
        {
            if (discoveryEndpoint == null) { 
                 discoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint(); 
            }

            discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(discoveryEndpoint);

            return discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (discoveryClient != null)
                {
                    discoveryClient.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                // Eat it.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the Stack Trace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
public static FindResponse Discover(FindCriteria findCriteria, DiscoveryEndpoint discoveryEndpoint = null)
{
    if (discoveryEndpoint == null) 
      discoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint();

    using (var client = new DiscoveryClient(discoveryEndpoint))
    {
        return client.Find(findCriteria);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Seems `DiscoveryClient.Dispose()` will throw exceptions.  OP's original approach seems like the only acceptable answer.

Comment: I should have thought of that. :) Thanks.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!! I'm getting the exception again! I may just have to catch it and eat it.

Comment: Oh, I've seen this same issue (Close and Dispose) with WCF clients.  Best to just eat it as you originally suggested.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867/closing-and-disposing-a-wcf-service

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not quite sure why you run into it, but you may try the following for normal WCF client:

If you have "State" property available on discoveryClient then, please try with following defensive checks:

```
finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (discoveryClient != null) 
                { 
                  if(discoveryClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                  {
                     discoveryClient.Abort();
                  }
                  else if(discoveryClient.State != CommunicationState.Closed )
                  {
                     discoveryClient.Close();
                  }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {

            }
        }
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Can't the state change between your `if` check and what's inside the `if`?

Comment: @BobHorn You are right. But from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationstate.aspx) , "Closing" state is transient and instead it would be better to do a check on non-transient state "Closed" and updated my answer accordingly. Also "Faulted" state is another where we should close the channel with Abort only. + As you mentioned originally, if all these states are slipped out for some reason, then better to swallow it :)

Comment: Thanks. With your example, we'd still need to catch and eat the exception, but at least the code is explicit in what it's doing. +1 for the tip, but I'm just going to catch and eat the exception without worrying about the other states. Sometimes you just get tired of writing code like this. :)

Comment: @BobHorn But if you go the route of defining a custom wrapper around your communication channel and then you can encapsulate this state handling into it so that you least bothered of spilling these state checks across code base.

Answer (score -1):

Also I would recommend to use "using" for the IDisposable objects. Considering DiscoveryClient is IDisposable,

```
public static FindResponse Discover(FindCriteria findCriteria, DiscoveryEndpoint discoveryEndpoint = null)
    {

        FindResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            if (discoveryEndpoint == null) { discoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint(); }

            using (DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(discoveryEndpoint))
            {
                response = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
                discoveryClient.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {   
            // other finalizing works, like clearing lists, dictionaries etc.
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but `finally {}` is a no-op.

Comment: @RichardSchneider, I think, I have edited the code right way. . .. .